# print option lost after Mountain Lion upgrade

Tags: macos, mac-mini, printing, canon

After I recently moved my data from a Mac Mini '09 to a new Mac Mini with Mountain Lion, I find my print options no longer allow me to print "fast"  (on Canon pixma mx712).  The print quality options now are "draft," "normal," and "best" but "draft" is greyed and not available.

Are there any settings I could look for and change?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the Presets drop-down in the Print window that comes up when you select Print (Command-P) in any app?

In this Print window, click on Show Details. There you can build your own Presets -- Draft, Fast, Slow, Color, Paper, whatever combination of variables you like -- by selecting from the choices shown and saving for future use.

BTW, to see this expanded Print window by default, enter in Terminal:

```
defaults write NSGlobalDomain PMPrintingExpandedStateForPrint -bool true
```